# Find the value of a when the given function is differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

[image]

For this question first I found out g(0) = -a. On evaluating the RHL and LHL the RHL Is 0 and the LHL is -a but since the given function is continuous on the interval I concluded that a is 0.

It's the second part of the question, I'm not very sure about. I used the formula of derivatives and found the limits of

lim(h->0) (f(o+h)-f(o))/h , for both the LHL and RHL and the LHL Is something like (h^3 - h -2a)/h , Hence I used the L'Hôpital's rule and  I end up losing a in the process and the RHL has no a and both of them seem to end up with different solutions. So does that mean the given function is not differentiable? Is my approach right or is there another way to go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

L'Hôpital's rule isn't useful for calculating derivatives with the definition:

$$f'(x) =  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dh}(f(x+h)-f(x))}{\frac{d}{dh} h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(x+h) - 0}{1} = \lim_{h\to 0} f'(x+h) = f'(x) $$
It is circular.

But, because the derivative can't have a first type of singularity (with both sides having a different finite limit), that means we can derive the left side function and the right side function and force them to be equal:
$$2x-1 = 3x^2 - 4 $$
At $x=0$ , so for which $a$ is this equation statement true: $ -1 = -4 $? None!
Meaning $g$ will never be differentiable at $x=0$.